# Problem solving $2\times 2$ equation system

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\left\{\begin{align}
2x + 3y &= 10 \\
4x -  y &= - 1
\end{align}\right.
$$
1) I don't get why I have to multiply first equation by $-2$ and not $+2$

2) How does $x=\frac{1}{2}$

I'm only $15$ so try and explain as simple as possible. Thanks.

Comment: You have to multiply it by $-2$ because then adding the two equation together $-4x$ from the multiple of the first equation will eliminate the $4x$ from the second one. Also $x=1/2$ and $y=3$ is the solution. I do not really understand this second question, because the problem with the first suggest that you have only seen it from some kind of solution.

Comment: Okay I get the bit now thanks,  can you explain why x = 1/2

Comment: You could multiply by $2$ as well. In that case however you would have to subtract the one equations from the other one. The point is that you want to get rid of one of the unknowns.

Comment: If you do the addition then you will get a new equation $-7y=-21$. From this $y=3$ and simply substitute it into one of the equations in the system. It will give you $x=1/2$. Also you can do the substraction like zoli mentioned.

Comment: How would one substitute it into the equation? It's a none calculator so I dont get how I would result in getting 1/2

Comment: See the answers.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(1) \  2x+3y = 10 \ 
\\ (2) \ 4x-y = -1 \ 
$$
Adding $-2*(1)$ to $(2)$:
$$
\\2x+3y=10
\\0x-7y=-21
$$
So clearly $y=3$, and from that follows that
$$
2x=1
\\x=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

it don't matter whether you multiply by the first equation by $2$ or $-2.$ what you want to do is to go from a set of simultaneous equations of two variables $x, y$ to an equation with just one variable. in this example you are trying to eliminate $x$ so that you end up with an equation in only $y.$

if we multiply the first equation by $2,$  we have 
$$\begin{align} 4x + 6y &= 20\\4x-y &=-1. \end{align}$$

subtracting $(2)$  from $(1),$  we have $$7y = 21 $$ which give you $y = 3.$  putting this in one of the original equations 
$$4x-y = -1 \to 4x -3 = -1 \to 4x = -1+3 = 2 .$$ that gives you $x = 1/2.$

had you multiplied by $(-2),$  you would have ended up with $$\begin{align} -4x - 6y &= -20\\4x-y &=-1. \end{align}$$

now instead of subtracting, you will add the two and get $y = 3$ again.

Comment: I really don't understand how you got the x =1/2 I get how you need to put it into a equation but I'm lost from therethere

Comment: @user243638, i have added few more steps. see if it makes it easier to see that $x = 1/2.$

Comment: How did you go from 4x-3=-1 to 4x=2